# How to list all activities on a Git branch?

Tags: git

Is there any (sequence of) Git command(s) that will give me the entire list of "activities" on a given branch? By "activity", I mean, some command that displays the following "history".

I have a branch called `testbranch` which was created on top of another branch, `remotebranch`, using these commands:

```
git checkout -b remotebranch
git checkout -b testbranch
```

1. (Creation) Branch 'testbranch' set up to track remote branch 'remotebranch'
2. (Commit) Commit1
3. (Syncing latest changes from remote) Merge branch 'remotebranch' of  into 'testbranch'
4. (Commit) Commit2
5. (and so on)

NOTE: I know about `git log`, but that displays all the commits for the entire repo, so I don't want that.

Comment: Consider `git reflog` as applied to the local branch, but note that (a) this is purely local information (it cannot tell you who did what to any other name for the branch elsewhere) and (b) reflogs expire (by default, after 90 days for reachable objects).

Comment: `git log --ancestry-path origin/develop..develop`

this will display all commits between origin develop and your develop. Maybe you will be able to use it